# SSH to jump server, check if service is running, if running execute command

Tags: python, networking, ssh, paramiko, netmiko

I need to make a python script which goes into a jump server, then pings a set of ip's from a list. If the ping is successful, i will then need to ssh into that ip, check if a particular service is running, and then run a command if service is running. If not running, no need to execute command. Can you please give me an idea of how to go through this?

Comment: Stack Overflow is neither a code-writing service nor a replacement for basic documentation and tutorials. Show us how you've tried to solve the problem and explain the specific problems you're having and we would be happy to help out.

Answer (score 0):

[Fabric](https://www.fabfile.org/) is maybe what you're looking for, it is a python library for executing shell commands remotely over ssh.